# How to display row inside a row in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to design travel page using angular js where I am stuck in showing seat layout.

Whenever I click in show details I want to show the seat layout under the clicked row. How do I achieve this?

My code:

```
<html ng-app="searchResults">
    <head>
       <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>

<style>
td{text-align:center;}
.animate.ng-enter, .animate.ng-leave {
  transition: 500ms ease-in all;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
} 

.animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active, .animate.ng-leave {
  left: 0;
}
.animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active, .animate.ng-enter {
  left: 500px;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="busesDiv" ng-controller="busesController">
<input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
<div style="width:100%;">
<table style="width:100%;" id="myT">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="head in busHeaders">{{ busHeaders[$index]}}  </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="bus in buses | filter:search" class="animate">
<td>{{bus.operatorName}}</td>
<td>{{bus.vehicleClass}}</td>
<td>{{bus.amenities}}</td>
<td>{{bus.departureTime}}</td>
<td>{{bus.arrivalTime}}</td>
<td>{{bus.availableSeats}}</td>
<td>{{bus.fare}}</br><button ng-click="showSeatDetails(bus,bus.busServiceId)">Show Details</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class"seatLayoutTable">
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="row in totalSeatConfiguration.split(';')">
    <td ng-repeat="seat in row.split(',') track by $index">
        <span ng-if="bookedSeatsArray.indexOf(seat.split('_')[0].trim())==-1 && ladiesSeatsArray.indexOf(seat.split('_')[0])==-1">
            <img src="images/available.png" ng-show="seat.split('_')[0] !='NA'" title="{{seat.split('_')[0]}}"/>
      </span>
       <span ng-if="bookedSeatsArray.indexOf(seat.split('_')[0])!=-1">
             <img src="images/booked.png" ng-show="seat.split('_')[0]!='NA'" title="{{seat.split('_')[0]}}"/>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="ladiesSeatsArray.indexOf(seat.split('_')[0])!=-1">
        <img src="images/ladies.png" ng-show="seat.split('_')[0]!='NA'" title="{{seat.split('_')[0]}}"/>
         </span>
       </td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The second table will display seat layout,but I want to add this layout to clicked row.

Comment: So put the second `ng-repeat` table inside the first? And then show/hide it with `ng-show`. Please don't use tables though, I'm guessing that's why you don't want to nest them...

Comment: If I put second ng-repeat inside the first,then same seat layout will add to all parent rows  and it is difficult to get which seat is clicked

Comment: Posted an answer to clarify

Answer (score 0):

First off, skip the tables. There's no reason to use them here. Second, make your `seats` children of the `bus`

```
<h1 ng-repeat="head in busHeaders">{{ busHeaders[$index]}}  </h1>

<div ng-repeat="bus in buses | filter:search" class="bus animate">
    <span>{{bus.operatorName}}</span>
    <span>{{bus.vehicleClass}}</span>
    <span>{{bus.amenities}}</span>
    <span>{{bus.departureTime}}</span>
    <span>{{bus.arrivalTime}}</span>
    <span>{{bus.availableSeats}}</span>
    <span>{{bus.fare}}</br>
    <button ng-click="bus.showSeats = !bus.showSeats">Show Details</button></span>

    <div class="seatLayout" ng-repeat="seat in bus.seats" ng-show="bus.showSeats">
        <span ng-show="!seat.booked" ng-click="seat.book()">
           <span ng-show="!seat.ladies"><img src="images/available.png"/></span>
           <span ng-show="seat.ladies"><img src="images/ladies.png"/></span>
        </span>
        <span ng-show="seat.booked"><img src="images/booked.png"/></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll of course have to refactor your data model and style everything appropriately. But you get the gist of how much you're overcomplicating something that's really relatively simple if you're using a straightforward data model.